# Cross-filter and dc acting weirdly

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

- I have five bar charts plotted using dc and cross-filter.
- The input to cross-filter changes with a drop-down i.e. whenever the
  user selects a metric in the drop-down, the cross-filter input
  changes
- Also, the metrics selected in the drop-down have different values to be plotted which I am handling using if conditions(check the value of **avgIndex** in if,else-if and else block)
- The graphs come out fine when metrics listed in if and else-if blocks are selected.However, when the remaining metrics (else block) are selected, the charts go haywire
- At first(when the metric of else block are selected) the graphs come out correctly, the moment I click on any of the bars(to put the filters on), the charts show irrelevant negative values(though the values of my metrics can't ever go negative, as per the data I have)
- Also, for same filters applied, I get different values across different charts at different instance of time, which is really weird.For the same filters applied, how can the data plotted be different at different instance of time?